# Azure Devops pipeline: waiting between jobs

Tags: azure-devops

I have a pipeline with three jobs:

1. Job 1 starts a background bash job (with nohup and &) that collects K8s metrics for 2 hours and then exits (so as to not occupy an agent for two hours). It also keeps track of the folder on which it runs, and is configured to always run on a specific agent.
2. Job 2 waits for 2 hours, with a Delay task.
3. Job 3, also configured to run on the same agent, enters the folder saved above, and uses the result of the metrics collection to do some calculations.

The problem is that, even though I have confirmed that it enters the right folder, it cannot find the result file. I have also used a little test, I touch a file in Job 1, and I cannot see it inside the folder in job 3. All I can see is the original contents, what existed before job 1 executed. The result file and the test-touch file are missing.

I save the folder in Job 1 with this command:

```
variables:
  Folder: $[ dependencies.job_1.outputs['job_1_folder.RUNNING_FOLDER'] ]
```

...and in job 3 I just cd to  $(Folder)

Any ideas? Either to fix the above, or perhaps to allow job 3 access to something that was produced in job 1 in a different way...

Comment: I would suggest to use predefined variables to save and edit your files. For example you could use a powershell task to copy files on `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` and then access those files from `Job 3`. Artifacts staging directory is the folder `a` inside your `build ID` run inside your `../work` directory (inside agent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Either to fix the above, or perhaps to allow job 3 access to something that was produced in job 1 in a different way...

It depends on the type of agent you are using.

If you are using the hosted agent, since every time an agent is allocated, MS will allocate a new agent to you, so the files you store in job1 will not be saved to job3.

To resolve this issue, you could check the idea mentioned by GeralexGR, using the task publish build artifact and donwload it in the job3 with downloadl build artifact task.

And if you are using the private agent, you need make sure the job1 and job3 are using same agent and not enable the clear option in the pipeline configration:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't know what you mean by "pipeline configuration", the pipeline is defined as a YAML file... The agent is picked from a pool that contains 5 agents, and I ensure it's the same as in job-1.

Comment: @GID, So, you are using the hosted agent, even if they are configured as the same agent pool, they will still be assigned as a clean agent for you to use. Otherwise all agents are tainted. You need to use publish build artifact task to publish your files and get them in next job